# Can you split both actions in the turn when using Quickness

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded

In Deadlands, Quickness says you gain an extra action instead of an extra turn.  Can you split both actions granted by Quickness?

Normally you can do more than one action if you apply a -2 to each action. So could you make two attacks at -2, then on the second granted action make two more attacks each at -2?

(Quickness feels kinda broken.)

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as “splitting an action” in the *Savage Worlds* rules. There is however the ability to take multiple actions in a turn.

> Characters may perform multiple actions such as Intimidating someone while blasting away
>   with a shotgun, running and Fighting, attacking with a weapon in each hand, and so on. […]
>
> Each additional action attempted in a round subtracts 2 from all the hero’s rolls. If an adventurer wants to fire a gun with one hand and slice at an adjacent foe with a sword in the other, for instance, he subtracts 2 from both rolls.
>
> <sub>*Savage Worlds Deluxe*, Chapter 3: Game Rules</sub>

What the *quickness* power does (as printed in *Deadlands Reloaded*) is grant an additional action without a penalty. So instead of both actions being at –2, both actions are without penalty (or alternatively, you can do three actions at –2, four at –4, etc). However, you still can’t do the same action twice (except for having a separate weapon in the other hand).

Note that the version printed in *Deadlands Reloaded* matches the version in *Savage Worlds Explorer’s Edition* (2007). *Savage Worlds Deluxe* (2011) changed the *quickness* power to adding a whole entire turn, thus avoiding the ambiguity.

> This power grants incredible swiftness to the recipient. With success the target has two separate turns per round on his action card instead of the usual one. Each turn is handled independently with its own actions, but the character must resolve one turn entirely before beginning the second.

If you are playing with *Savage Worlds Deluxe* as your core rules, then note that the official *[Deadlands Deluxe-ified](https://www.peginc.com/store/deadlands-deluxe-ified-pdf/)* PDF supplement says to use those rules instead of the ones in the *Player's Guide*:

> The power descriptions in the *Deadlands Player’s Guide* are superseded by the *Savage Worlds Deluxe* versions (but Trappings are unchanged).

<sub>I tend to agree that *quickness* is overpowered, especially in its *Deluxe* version, but that’s how the rules work.</sub>

Comment: Its worth noting that Deadlands powers have officially been updated to those in the Deluxe core book. https://www.peginc.com/store/deadlands-deluxe-ified-pdf/

Comment: @Wibbs Updated. You are correct that, if they are playing with *Deluxe* core rules, rather than *Explorer's Edition* core rules, they ought to be using that PDF supplement which says to use the ones in *Deluxe* over the ones in the DLR book.